# ReactJS when triggering an event from child component inside map() function, the index is always zero back to the parent

Tags: reactjs, json

I used ASP.NET MVC React template so the parent is a Class component and the child is a function component.

This is an example of the object:

```
invitation: {
    mainName: "Joe Bloggs",
    mainEmailAddress: "joe@hotmail.com",
    invitees: [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Joe Bloggs",
        "email": "joe@hotmail.com",
        "drinking": "",
        "diet": "",
        "rsvp": ""
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "John Smith",
        "email": "john@hotmail.com",
        "drinking": "",
        "diet": "",
        "rsvp": ""
      }
    ]
  }
```

In the Parent component

```
    this.state.invitation.invitees.map((guest, index) =>{
                          return (<RsvpForm key={guest.id} translations={this.translations} context={context.state} invitee={guest} index={index} handleOnChange={this.updateGuest} />);
  }) : null
                      }
```

The updateGuest function (in the parent component)

```
  updateGuest = (e, i) => {

const name = e.target.name;
const value = e.target.value;

this.setState(prevState => {
  return {
    invitation: {
      ...prevState.invitation,
      invitees: [...prevState.invitation.invitees.slice(0, i),
      { ...prevState.invitation.invitees[i], [name]: value },
      ...prevState.invitation.invitees.slice(i + 1)]
    }

  }
});
```

}

And the RSVP form (Child Component). The form has more HTML elements but I am pasting the crucial part

```
            <div className="mb-2" >
            <label className="form-label">{getTranslation(props.context, 'RSVP')}</label>
            <div className="row" >
                <div className="col-auto">
                    <input type="radio" onChange={(e) => props.handleOnChange(e, props.index)} checked={props.invitee.rsvp == "Yes"} className="btn-check" name="rsvp" id="success-outlined" autoComplete="off" value="Yes" />
                    <label className="btn btn-outline-success" htmlFor="success-outlined">{getTranslation(props.context, 'Yes')}</label>

                </div>
                <div className="col-auto d-none d-sm-block d-md-none" />

                <div className="col-auto">
                    <input type="radio" onChange={(e) => props.handleOnChange(e, props.index)} checked={props.invitee.rsvp == "No"} className="btn-check" name="rsvp" id="danger-outlined" autoComplete="off" value="No" />
                    <label className="btn btn-outline-danger" htmlFor="danger-outlined">No</label>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

This renders correctly. I can see two forms one for Joe Bloggs and one for John Smith.

However since the `handleOnChange` passes the index back to the parent to update the corresponding property of the invitee that was clicked, the index is always 0, not matter which one I click, even though, when rendering I can see 0 and 1 respectively.

Hence when John Smith RSVPs, it actually changes Joe's RSVP.

Can anyone figure out what I am missing here?

Comment: so inside your `updateGuest = (e, i) => {` you `console.log(i)` and you get always 0?

Comment: @Apostolos yes that's what's happening

Comment: very weird. from what i see i cannot spot a problem.

Comment: just for curiosity... if you replace index with id does it console.log the correct one?

Comment: @Apostolos replacing index with id, does the same thing except that it is always 1 (as in the first item always)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a fixed id in the component especially if it's going to be repeated.

You can modify your code in the child component like below:

`id={"success-outline" + props.index}`

You may change the name of the radio group name as well.

Comment: Thanks Capsen. That fixed my issue. 
I had seen other implementations with fixed id. The difference was that I needed to read the value from those repeated html controls. If you just need to display, you can get away with it